Why did Borland ignore the Macintosh market?
During the 80s and 90s, Borland developed several amazing, cutting edge developer products. Their Turbo Pascal and Delphi, an Object Pascal development environment, were very popular on DOS and Windows. Slowly over time, however, Borland lost the fight against Microsoft, even though their products were technically superior to Microsoft's offerings.
For reasons I cannot understand, however, Borland completely ignored the Macintosh market. It seems they preferred charging absurdly low prices just to stay afloat than to expand into the Macintosh market. It would have been the ideal market given Pascal was the lingua franca for Macintosh development for years.
Oddly, enough, while Borland was slowly losing the market to Microsoft, other vendors prospered selling Pascal compilers exclusively for the Macintosh. Think Technologies did well and was eventually acquired by Symantec. Eventually, they exited the market, leaving Metrowerks, a small startup, to dominate the market. Eventually, Metrowerks was attractive enough to be acquired by Motorola in the early 2000s.

They didn't ignore the Mac: https://winworldpc.com/product/turbo-pascal/1x-mac

I am quite sure it is the same answer as for other companies that didn't cross develop: PC and Mac has only one thing in common: they are both computers. Everything else differs: How open the system is. How to use the underlying structure of windows. What CPU is used. Even the endianness differ on the CPUs. Today most (even free) dev packages handles this with ease, but in the end of the 80s, beginning of the 90s it was a different situation.

The page linked above probably sums it up: "under powered and closed Macintosh 128k architecture. While at the same time Apple had not been very supportive of third party development tools."

I have difficulty taking the ‘underpowered’ argument seriously given that Turbo Pascal was also available for CP/M; it’s also hard to see how open/closed architecture is relevant given that Borland shipped for IBM while that company was still deploying lawyers everywhere to keep its architecture closed. With no citation provided whatsoever, my first guess would be that the linked page is the usual internet warrior trying to write a partisan history.

@Tommy - to be fair, the original Mac was pretty slow to the user because it had the overhead of the graphic environment. The Turbo products prided themselves on pretty snappy text-mode response, and turning that over to the graphical-mode OS would seem painful to the developers.

I don't think anyone other than the likes of Phillippe Kahn could give a definitive answer to this.

@JonCuster the dearth of RAM was the huge speed issue; the UI wasn't too much of an issue, especially at the Borland IDE level of text editing and some menus. These are the same machines that popularised desktop publishing, as PageMaker was first introduced in 1985, a couple of years before the Macintosh II. Raffzahn's answer of, in effect, the Mac wasn't sufficiently profitable compared to other platforms, has much more credibility than some anonymous nonsense about 'open' platforms.

@JonCuster Well, yes and no. While GUI was an overhead compared to text mode, it wasn't as bad. Toolbox routines were usually reasonable well written. The biggest speed bump was RAM. 128 KiB total, including OS, OS data and screen was simply not much, often leaving less than what a CP/M system could offer. Non trivial Mac applications relied heavy on overlays - which made everything slower than slow ... and Mac user used to waiting for every operation :)) Also something TP wasn't really made for at the time. RAM was THE Mac issue.

The memory limitations of the Macintosh, if any, can't be a significant reason, since Borland sold a compiler for it when it had a tiny footprint.

@ATL_DEV Not really. Version 1.0 for Mac required already at least 256 KiB of RAM. thus it could not run on an original Mac but required a Fat Mac or Mac Plus.

@Raffzahn " RAM was THE Mac issue." == Maybe that caused long compilation times, but overlays  wouldn't have slowed down the IDE very much. A control like a drop down doesn't take very long to load, and once it's loaded, it's resident.  That's what matters. Long compile times were normal in those days.

Macs were rare and expensive so the home market was very small.  I only know one who bought it for herself, everybody else bought PC’s. Hence very small marked for cheap, fast but limited products.

If you're still wanting it, these days Delphi runs fine on mac.

At only 10% to 15% marketshare, many misperceive the Macintosh as not as lucrative as PCs. However, the Macintosh transformed entire industries and professions, making it an indispensible fixture among creative professionals. It dominated publishing, print, design, music, and video. Many of the largest software companies today started out on the Macintosh platform, including Adobe, one of the largest software companies in the world.

@JessFuckett The whole point of Turbo Pascal was in memory compilation without loading one or multiple compiler overlays. With just 128 KiB there wasn't enough RAM to do so - at least not for anything past Hello World. Also, Pascal was already the main development language for the Mac and well supported. Making TP like the existing compiler would have made it rather pointless.

@ATL_DEV You may mix up 40 years with way different phases. Likewise being remarkable or even worse, remembered does not make anything a success or viable product. Even less dominating. Those are rather subjective categories. For Video the the Dazzler might have had more impact than the Mac - and for sure the Amiga. Likewise the Atari is what everyone found (and still finds) in music studios and on stage. And so on. Also, Apple never had 15 or even only 10% of the PC market back then .. and, despite all recent success, still not today. Let's try to stay objective on RC.SE.

@Raffzahn: If one wanted to design a compiler for text-based applications that was compatible with Turbo Pascal on other platforms (80x34 drawn on as bitmap) I would think 107K (subtracting out the dedicated 21K frame buffer) would be more than enough for a compiler patterned on Turbo Pascal 3.0 (editing and running programs in RAM, or writing a binary executable blob which could be run in Mac OS with the aid of a helper application, or copied to the helper application's data form so it could auto-start.

@Raffzahn My stats for Macintosh marketshare during the 80-90s phase are based on US sales. Amiga and Atari had some small niche markets in music and video, but eventually the Macintosh supplanted both. Borland was still relevant when it happened.

Completely opinion based, but Pascal just wasn't a big language in the 1980s. Yes, there were a lot of hobbyists that used Turbo-Pascal, especially toward the end of the decade. But my experience was that all development on the PC at that time used C (or assembly, but that was limited too). Pure Pascal was, quite frankly, not a great language for developing "real" apps. If you look back at old computer magazines, you'll see a lot of articles about Module 2 as a "better, more useful Pascal". But I never knew a company that used it either.

@kdgregory - I worked for an early CAD company - Vector Automation, Baltimore, MD in the very early 80s - that used Pascal on an HP2100 for all its software.  I know because I wrote the compiler we used.  (Before that they used FORTRAN but it wasn't really suitable for how we wanted to work.)  (I also know that one anecdote isn't generalizable to the entire industry.  But people were using Pascal, quite a few, it wasn't niche.  Though it was not as popular as C+assembler.). (Modula 2 though was strictly academic, as far as I knew at the time.)

@davidbak - I suppose language choice largely depends on the industry and platform.

I forgot to mention REAL Software. Their REALBasic program was similar to Delphi and was fairly successful.

@kdgregory: Turbo Pascal on the PC was used by more than "hobbyists".  While there were limits to what it could do, developing applications that fit well within its abilities (especially with the aid of an in-line assembler tool when necessary to produce files that could be included within Pascal source) was much faster than trying to do the same thing in any other language.  Pascal was also dominant on the Macintosh.


Why did Borland ignore the Macintosh market?

It didn't. There was a short lived Turbo Pascal 1.0 (as UncleBod mentions). Even before Turbo Pascal, Borland ported Sidekick as well as their Reflex database for Mac.

(Taken from the back side of Turbo Pascal for the Macintosh)
But yeah, development stopped by 1988 and it all comes down to size, size and size. Plus product type and to a lesser extent environment.
Size, Size and Size
Back in the 80s the computer market was unbelievably tiny compared to today, and within the professional segment (read: non-home/hobby), the Mac was at best third or fourth in size, trailing way behind MS-DOS, CP/M-86 and even CP/M-80 (*1). Best illustrated by the fact that Apple needed 4 years ('84-'87) to sell the first million units. The 'old' 8 Bit Apple II sold a good 3.5 Million during the same period (*2).
During the same period IBM PC and compatible clones sold more than 15 Million (*3) units. This means Borland would have to invest a similar amount in development and marketing for a market only 6-7% the size. Doesn't sound great for a sales-oriented company.
Product type
Turbo Pascal, the main product of Borland in the mid 1980s (introduced Christmas 1983), was CP/M software. Meant to run on a rather frugal environment using a character-based frontend with terminal type control (in-band signalling). Getting that to DOS (*4) wasn't a big deal, as it didn't offer any notable improvement over CP/M (*5). Pascal did cover those basics quite well, great for cross development between CP/M (*1) and DOS (*6).
Mac applications work completely different. No CLI, no text-based graphics or even cursor keys, plus Mac screen-handling being all about proportional text, something alien to character-based terminal programs. Any port requires a complete rewrite of the UI - which as we all know can easy reach 90% of all application code. This completely kills any dream of portability. Mac development was a different world done in separate departments, just ask Microsoft.
It was no real goal for Borland to invest in developing GUI features into (Turbo) Pascal as there was no GUI for either of their markets (*7). It took until 1987 to include graphics (BGI) as a core part (*8,*9) and it wasn't until 1990 that Turbo Vision added (somewhat *10) serious support for GUI.
Environment
The different front end structure was already mentioned, but the (original) Mac was even more restricted due its hardware. With just 128 KiB, the memory situation was worse than on an 8-bit computer. At the same time, it couldn't do 80 characters per line - something every DOS program would expect.
I would like to think that the often-cited 'shortcomings' are only about Turbo Pascal, not Sidekick or Reflex, as both were ported before Pascal and to the original 1984 Mac. 1985 brought the 512 KiB Mac, removing the biggest obstacle, for Borland to port Turbo Pascal. A good indication is also that the 1.0 Version required 256 KiB minimum RAM (*11).


During the 80s and 90s, Borland developed several amazing, cutting edge developer products.

Not so much, as they were buying most.

Their Turbo Pascal and Delphi, an Object Pascal development environment,

Delphi might sound old today, but it only debuted in 1995, at a time when the Mac/PC quota was even worse than in 1987 and at the same time the total Apple numbers were still not high enough either.

were very popular on DOS and Windows.

You may want to add CP/M to that. It was the important kickstart for Borland to cover the vast existing base of CP/M - and support the move from CP/M to MS-DOS that happened exactly at the time when Turbo Pascal was introduced. Not to mention the great public success in Europe with systems like the CPC.

Slowly over time, however, Borland lost the fight against Microsoft, even though their products were technically superior to Microsoft's offerings.

Which might be debatable. They'd been a leader on the CP/M to DOS move, but missed the transition from DOS to Windows. Sure, Delphi was great, but it was way too late. When Win 3.x became a hit after 1990, Borland's main feature was still text-based. Windows support in version 6 and 7 was quite clumsy. So any early and not so early developer for Windows looking for a compiler had to use MS - possibly even MS-Pascal. By the time Delphi came in 1995, only a few professional developers hadn't switched to a more Windows enabled environment - which usually meant C.

It seems they preferred charging absurdly low prices just to stay afloat than to expand into the Macintosh market.

Low price was always the main argument to buy Borland. It undercut any other supplier by far. 50 USD was about a quarter of what any other compiler would cost. It was so low that people chose it who otherwise would not have bought anything.

It would have been the ideal market given Pascal was the lingua franca for Macintosh development for years.

Not least that the Mac itself was done in Pascal.

Oddly, enough, while Borland was slowly losing the market to Microsoft, other vendors prospered selling Pascal compilers exclusively for the Macintosh.

The same way as language developers flourished in other niche markets.

*1 - While CP/M systems might've no longer been top-selling in the mid 1980s, it's the installed base applications get programmed for. Same reason why there's still a good market for COBOL even today. New machines sell with new OSes, but all machines are served by later application development. So having a way to offer Software for CP/M-80 customers and MS-DOS with little or no variation gives a great incentive to using TP.
*2 - Not to mention the installed base, which adds >1M for Apple II and zero for the Mac.
*3 - According to the same numbers, which to me look a bit US-specific. So while the PC:Mac ratio might be similar in other parts of the world, those areas may have had some variation.
*4 - After all, DOS always was just a somewhat modernized CP/M clone.
*5 - Better file handling system calls aren't really a point once file handling is wrapped (abstracted) by a HLL.
*6 - In fact, I earned some change on side projects in 1984, programmed for PC users, but developed under CP/M-80 on my Apple II :))
*7 - Well, by 1987 it was MS-DOS only, as 3.0 was the last published for CP/M-80.
*8 - There was a graphics toolbox added separate product with 3.0.
*9 - 1987's Version 4 also marks the point when it first enabled production of EXE files, allowing more than 64 KiB of code - easy to forget how primitive TP was compared to 'real' compilers :)
*10 - Turbo Vision was primarily text-based, but allowed transition to a GUI by working with menu, dialog and window abstraction instead of plain text. Kind of like IBM's SNA.
*11 - Shortly before Borland introduced 1.0, Apple finally gave us the Mac Plus with all the goodies of the 512ke plus SCSI plus a base RAM of 1 MiB, expandable to 4 MiB, finally a size enabling serious work. INHO the point from which the Mac can rally be classified as a PC. In 1987 the Mac II series was introduced and Borland upgraded Pascal to 1.1, supporting its 68020 as well.

“So any early and not so early developer for Windows looking for a compiler had to use MS - often MS-Pascal” — re the last part, I don’t think MS Pascal ever supported Windows. Early developers for Windows used C...

@StephenKitt Not sure, my memory tells me there was a lot of Pascal in MSJ aroudn 1990, and I remember at least one application out management wanted to use that was written in Pascal (they requested us to write a validator for some identifiers that would be included by its supplier). Also having win 3.0 bindings for MS Pascal. I did, at the time, write Win 3.0 in assembly, so me is no autority about that :)) Others migh have had different experience. Also I remember a heavy push for C by MS in the early 1990s.

The "primitive" design of Turbo Pascal versions up to 3 is what allowed them to be lightning-fast even on floppy-based machines.  The use of a separate linking step may have allowed programs to be built in environments with very limited memory, but could also be seen as a concession to limited-memory systems which shouldn't be as necessary today.

It's ironic how Borland had a rough start with GUIs, but later outshined the competition with its Delphi platform. Even to this day, no other development platform comes close to matching its productivity. It's a crying shame it wasn't available on the Mac which had a fairly primitive GUI tools. Apple should have coaxed them into supporting the Macintosh.

@Raffzahn I stand corrected, the 1987 languages brochure does mention Windows support in MS Pascal. But since the compiler was discontinued in 1989 I don’t think it would have been used by many developers on Windows 3.0.

Wow, text-based Microsoft Project.

@StephenKitt Nice find. Copied. Thank you. As said, the original wording was based on my memory of the time. Changes in culture (like moving Pascal to C) always take a while until they reach the field. Anyway, reworded it. Hope that better reflects your experience.

@ATL_DEV: I don't know how nicely adaptable Delphi would have been to the Macintosh.  I've designed applications on the classic Macintosh OS, and it had its own ways of handling controls with resources.  I can imagine a Macintosh version of Delphi could have ignored those in favor of doing things its own way (which I think is how apps like MS Word were designed) but I don't know if that would fit user needs more or less well than using "conventional" Mac-OS ways of doing things.  I'm also curious whether it might have been...

@ATL_DEV: ...practical to have development OS which unloaded Mac OS in favor of a minimalist disk operating system to make more RAM available for development tools.

Another point that is perhaps obvious, but isn't explicitly mentioned here: in addition to the GUI for the IDE itself, nobody was going to write text-based programs for the Mac. So a compiler designed to develop Mac software would have to incorporate support for working with all the Toolbox routines in the Mac ROM, compiling to resource/data forks, etc. It would be a completely separate product from their PC offerings.

@miken32 Oh, I thought it was obvious. A system made for Terminals is usually also made to only create such software. Likewise any ported software would only do so. But you're right, I should have pointed that out in a more direct way.

@miken32 True, it would be a separate product of course,  but Delphi's GUI code was heavily abstracted away from Win32 in much the same as .NET does. Of course, there's some differences in UI conventions, but the core plumbing is mostly there.

@miken32: If one wanted to generate code that would behave as "plug-ins" for a static base application, one would want to have a compiler know the names, trap number, argument list, and calling convention for all of the OS and Toolbox functions, as well as a means of handling imports from other plug-ins, but things wouldn't be all that different from the PC.

@miken32: Indeed, while the normal way of implementing plug-ins would be to use code-blob resources with a 32-bit type specifier chosen based upon expected calling convention (WDEF, INIT, XCMD, etc.), I don't think anything would have prevented a compiler from throwing all of the code in the data fork, and having a fixed collection of CODE resources in the resource fork which would read the contents of the data fork as a blob and execute it.

No one seems to have mentioned the fact that Turbo Pascal generated 8086 code directly. This would have to be changed (dramatically?) in order to output 68000 code.

@No'amNewman Usually not a big deal as Pascal is a rather frugal in it's need - and most x86 addressing modes have a similar way on the 68k. Note also that they DID produce a version, so that part might have been non-issue

@StephenKitt - FWIW, circa 1996 I was working with a company that had developed a Mac product and wanted to port it to Windows (1.0). There were ginormous differences between the Windows API and the Mac Toolbox, but iirc one of the bigger issues was that the calling convention was reversed between Pascal and C; we looked into generating Pascal bindings. Maybe that was just a Win 1.0 thing, and MS provided Pascal bindings later. Or maybe my memory is failing (that was, after all, only 3-4 months of my life nearly 40 years ago).

s/1996/1986/, although most of the "can we run this in Windows" was late 85. By early 86 they had pretty much abandoned that idea, as they were getting behind on the Mac version (I ended up spending a couple of months helping them get over the line -- writing in Pascal -- and remember learning of the Challenger disaster while in their offices).

From what I can tell, Borland regained a lot of users with Delphi, mainly because the MS counter-part MFC was just a thin layer above the raw Windows API and a complete pain to work with in terms of productivity - it was not really a "RAD" tool. To the point where MS had to come up with VB to at least keep some market share. Then came C++ Builder, once again to attract users away from MS. Visual Studio remained useless for RAD until .NET came around in the early 2000s.

I don't think Borland were outcompeted by MS as much as by completely free open source compilers. There was simply no longer a profitable market for the compiler business. MS too eventually had to come up with free alternatives to stick around as a compiler.

I asked Phillippe Kahn when he visited Microsoft in the mid 1990s. He said the Mac market share was just too small for them to devote many resources to Mac software, and that they frequently reevaluated their position because tons of nerds like me made the same requests.

Thanks!  Kahn's decision wasn't a shrewd one. The Mac was certainly profitable enough for Adobe, Microsoft, and Metrowerks. Not surprising, Borland also abandoned their Ada compiler project which would have revolutionized software development as we know it. At the very least, they would have survived as a government vendor.

Easy for you to say. By the mid '90s they had spread themselves pretty thin (to me that was probably the main problem), and Apple was really struggling. It wasn't clear to all of us they would survive.

@ATL_DEV Keep in mind that Microsoft was with the Mac from the start, as a preferred partner with no competition (Word for Mac outsold Word for DOS and Windows combined). Also Gates loved the Mac - after all, Windows was only pushed after Apple rejected the idea to do a PC version. Next, Jobs owned a major (20%?) slice of Adobe and apple was their launch customer for Postscript - they couldn't really refuse. And last, Metrowerks only entered the Mac Market in the mid 1990s, again with a good push by Apple. So neither of those three, being that special, make a great example for other companies.

The market for developer applications - i.e., compilers and tools - is now, was then, always has been miniscule relative to the market for "typical user" applications.  Sufficient market in the one area doesn't translate into sufficient for the other.  MetroWerks did get traction and was great (Raffzahn reminds that that was with Apple's help, and later than Borland's start).  But at the time Borland - also a small company - was arguably right to stay focused on the PC market.

@ATL_DEV - do you have any references (links) to information on Borland's Ada compiler project?  I've never heard of it (and I was in the Ada compiler writing business at Softech and Alsys and was keeping track of related projects then and later).  I'm very interested!

@Raffzahn Apple gave them a good push? It must have been over a cliff, because Metrowerks, or rather Motorola, had their lunch eaten by Xcode. They pulled out of the Mac market and focused on the embedded market.

@ATL_DEV - and that in a nutshell was the problem with developer tools back then.  Two related problems:  Problem #1 was that companies employing developers hated hated hated spending any money whatsoever on developer tools.  So problem #2 was that in order to get traction for their platform Microsoft and Apple had to have all the developer tools and SDKs their platform needed.  Both initially charged money for it.  Apple more than Microsoft.  It was a real blocker for potential Apple devs.  Microsoft saw the light first and made their tools free (the command line versions of the tools).

@ATL_DEV Which happened about a decade later. Also, not so sure how Motorola's later decision changes it - even more as it was you who cited Metrowerks as an example for success in the Mac market.

Apple was still charging, upwards of $500/developer seat IIRC.  The decision by Microsoft (the Windows team overriding the tools team) created a total legion of Windows developers.  But meanwhile, independent dev tool companies were sunk as Microsoft and Apple would just built into their tools features pioneered by the independents.  (To this day it's a race between Whole Tomato's Visuall Assist and Visual Studio for features.). But Microsoft/Apple can afford tool teams that are much much bigger than the independent companies.

@davidbak VisualAssist? Talk about the underdog. You have to hand it to them, they really defended their lunch against Resharper, CodeRush, Telerik. That is until Microsoft, like a croc in the water, made them all their lunch!

@davidbak Borland was working on a secret "Turbo Ada" project but it was scrapped. Niels Jenson, a cofounder of Borland, left with company with some other developers to work on such a compiler.
https://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=Borland+Ada+compiler&d=4717927512804908&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=lw-wtLwg7pRhd0vb3r7-obY3pBoWX2WV

Borland held a trademark for "Turbo Ada". I don't know why, but when I think of "Turbo Ada" I think of Judas Priest's "Turbo Lover".
https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=73674117&caseSearchType=US_APPLICATION&caseType=DEFAULT&searchType=statusSearch

@davidbak can you provide more context on "Microsoft saw the light first and made their tools free (the command line versions of the tools)."? Which release are you thinking of? I'm currently unable to find any reference to Microsoft offering free development tools prior to Visual Studio Express 2005, which obviously isn't what you're thinking of for at least two reasons — too late, not only command line.

Well I set up and run Ashton*Tates European Macintosh software, Translation and QA Department. Who you ask? Well late 80's they were bigger than Microsoft or as big. Dbase Anyone?
They had put together a suite of Mac applications - a SpreadSheet FullImpact, Word Processor FullWrite, and a graphics package. In a company marketing meeting I suggested we put them all in the same box and sell them as a business solution (before office was a thing). Everyone laughed! but I laughed last ;-)
While I was there they hit hard times as DBase4 was failing and competitors where taking their market share - clipper anyone? We were having weekly jokes about the Borland flag being raised at the front of the building...
Well Borland did take over and The Mac software range was first to go and no more or my job...

Interesting story, but I'm not so sure how it would answer the question.

It sort of points to the problems selling popular PC software in the Mac world. Except as pointed out, Ashton-Tate ended up with problems everywhere.

Your bundling idea was way ahead of its time. They chose not to listen.

My idea seemed logical to me. Microsoft were already in the market, they A*T were coming late. There apps were as good as theirs but they wernt an established player. By selling the 3 apps bundled for half as much they might sell 5 to 10 times as many.... making more money and getting larger market share.
